# serverless many functions in a project

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

Does it matter if I have many functions in one serverless project? Even if they are independent of each other. I was thinking that the only thing it did was make the zip file big.

So if I initiate a serverless project, and code 10 lambda functions, that are not connected in any way.

This is the same as initiating 10 serverless projects with 1 lambda function each.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear what you are asking about.

The Serverless framework was created partly because to group many functions in a single project. If you prefer splitting the project into multiple projects then, of course, you can do it and it may even have some advantages, for example, to do the versioning separately, to have independent pull requests in different repos etc.

I wouldn't split the project just for the sake of having one function per project but there may be other reasons.

To answer your question: Does it matter? Yes, it does, because it means a different project and a different workflow. You didn't tell us what is your main concern and why do you want to split the project so it's hard to tell you anything more not knowing with respect to what aspect "does it matter."

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood the server-less framework, you guys have provided. Your answer clears it up.

While I am here, is there a conventional way to load in the secret key to generate tokens?

Also, if I make an API gateway, trigger a lambda which then triggers a step function, how do I get the output of the step function back to the original API request.

Thanks for the info